# Parsing file in order to create a dictionary

Tags: python, file, dictionary

Text file I am working with

```
Al:dog-walking:2:painting:1
Bob:dog-walking:1:knife-sharpening:3
Carol:cleanup:1:dog-walking:2:painting:1
```

The desired dictionary to return looks like

```
{('Al','dog-walking'): 2,
('Al','painting'): 1,
('Bob','dog-walking'): 1,
('Bob','knife-sharpening'): 3,
('Carol','cleanup'): 1,
('Carol','dog-walking'): 2,
('Carol','painting'): 1}
```

This is my current code which produces an almost correct result

```
def readdb(file):             
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for line in open('formelol'):
        f=line.strip().split(':')
        c=f[0]
        x=tuple((c,f[1]))
        z=tuple((c,f[3]))
        d[x]=int(f[2])
        d[z]=int(f[4])
    return d

print(readdb(file='formelol'))
```

Returns:

```
{('Al', 'dog-walking'): 2, 
('Al', 'painting'): 1, 
('Bob', 'dog-walking'): 1, 
('Bob', 'knife-sharpening'): 3, 
('Carol', 'cleanup'): 1, 
('Carol', 'dog-walking'): 2})
```

I am missing the last line of `('Carol','painting'): 1}`

This code to me is a bit hardcoded.

My question is if there is a more pythonic way to produce these results and if so how would I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split each line and use extended unpacking to separate the name then pair everything that remains and assign to a normal `dict`, eg:

```
d = {}
with open('your_file_name') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        name, *rest = line.split(':')
        for activity, number in zip(rest[::2], rest[1::2]):
            d[(name, activity)] = int(number)
```

That gives you a `d` of:

```
{('Al', 'dog-walking'): 2,
 ('Al', 'painting'): 1,
 ('Bob', 'dog-walking'): 1,
 ('Bob', 'knife-sharpening'): 3,
 ('Carol', 'cleanup'): 1,
 ('Carol', 'dog-walking'): 2,
 ('Carol', 'painting'): 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a defaultdict for your use case.

I would replace

```
f=line.strip().split(':')
c=f[0]
x=tuple((c,f[1]))
z=tuple((c,f[3]))
d[x]=int(f[2])
d[z]=int(f[4])
```

with

```
k0, *rest = line.strip().split(':')
for k1, v in zip(rest[::2], rest[1::2]):
   d[(k0, k1)] = int(v)
```

Comment: Seems like that does not work. Since the third line has more values than the first line. I made a mistake thinking mine produced the correct result

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to extract alternate elements from array and create dictionary.

```py
d = {}
for line in open('formelol'):
    f=line.strip().split(':')
    name= f[0]
    values = f[1:]
    for i in range(len(values[1::2])):
        d[(name, values[0::2][i])] = values[1::2][i]
d
```

It will give you following result.

```
{('Al', 'dog-walking'): '2',
 ('Al', 'painting'): '1',
 ('Bob', 'dog-walking'): '1',
 ('Bob', 'knife-sharpening'): '3',
 ('Carol', 'cleanup'): '1',
 ('Carol', 'dog-walking'): '2',
 ('Carol', 'painting'): '1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip()` function:

```
s = '''Al:dog-walking:2:painting:1
Bob:dog-walking:1:knife-sharpening:3
Carol:cleanup:1:dog-walking:2:painting:1'''

d = {}
for line in s.splitlines():
    l = line.split(':')
    for i, j in zip(l[1::2], l[2::2]):
        d[(l[0], i)] = int(j)
print(d)
```

Prints:

```
{('Al', 'dog-walking'): 2, ('Al', 'painting'): 1, ('Bob', 'dog-walking'): 1, ('Bob', 'knife-sharpening'): 3, ('Carol', 'cleanup'): 1, ('Carol', 'dog-walking'): 2, ('Carol', 'painting'): 1}
```